# Error "The specified resource does not exist" when trying to copy blob from storage to another

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to move a blob file from a container to another that is in another storage.

```
public void MoveFile(StorageConfig sourceConfig, StorageConfig destinationConfig, string sourceFilename, string destinationFilename)
    {
        var sContainer = GetBlobContainerReference(sourceConfig.ConnectionString, sourceConfig.ContainerName);
        var dContainer = GetBlobContainerReference(destinationConfig.ConnectionString, destinationConfig.ContainerName);

        var sBlob = sContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceFilename);
        var dBlob = dContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(destinationFilename);

        dBlob.StartCopy(sBlob);

        sBlob.Delete(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
    }
```

I have distinct credentials for Source and Destination containers.

When I run this code, the error occurs on the line dBlob.StartCopy(sBlob);

And the error "The specified resource does not exist" is thrown.

The sBlob.Delete() works with no error, so it is reaching the source blob file.

I watch these variables:

```
sBlob.Exists() -> true
dBlob.Exists() -> false
sContainer.Exists() -> true
dContainer.Exists() -> true
```

So it can connect in both containers.

Did I need to create the destination blob first? I think not based on some codes I found in the internet.

Answer (score 2):

For copying blob from one account to another, the source blob must be publicly accessible. This restriction does not apply when a blob is copied within same storage account.

The reason you are getting this error is most likely because your source blob is in a private container.

To fix this issue, create a SAS URL for the source blob with at least `read` permission and use that URL for copying blob.

Comment: Is this a problem even if I'm using credentials? This storage must keep private, so I think I must download and upload the file, right?

Comment: Yes. This is because the copy blob operation is a server side async operation. You can still keep the storage account private. Just create a SAS URL with read permission for a limited time (say 5 minutes) so that the blob is publicly available for the copy operation to complete for that time only.